# C++ casablanca vs Mozilla NSPR vs Facebook folly

Tags: c++, cross-platform, casablanca, nspr

Has anyone evaluated these libraries for their pros and cons as a **cross-platform library**?

I understand NSPR is very old and stable, but how does it compare to Microsoft Casablanca C++ rest SDK and Facebook folly.

Microsoft Casablanca is capable of running on iOS and Android.

But if I am looking for supporting only OSX, Linux and Windows which one should I go with and why?

Is there any other cross-platform library I should look at?

Comment: A cross-platform library for what?

Comment: Yes, there is one other cross-platform library worth mentioning: http://cpp-netlib.org/

Comment: @bamboon cross-platform for networking, threading etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was look for a cross platform HTTP client in C++. The following link gives a brief on many options available there,

http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/a-cheat-sheet-for-http-libraries-in-c